# Replace video with still image using CSS

Tags: html, css, video

I am creating a print-css file for HTML5 documents containing video files. The video tags inside of a table look like this:

```
<td class="dataKeyframe">
  <video width="180" height="135" controls="controls" preload="none"
         poster="../images/sequenzbild001.jpg">
     <source type="video/mp4" src="../videos/mp4/E1.mp4"></source>
  </video>
</td>
```

Printing with Chrome results in printing the controls-overlay on top of the video poster.

The question:
Is it possible to set the controls to kind of `display:none;` --OR-- replace the video with the jpeg defined in the poster attribute? Using CSS only and not touching the html document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to alter is the **Shadow DOM** of the element. There are some browser generated subtree elements to display all those controls, panels and buttons browser dependently. Those are not displayed (at least not in chrome) in the source code but you can still play with them.

```
@media print {
    video::-webkit-media-controls {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//css
@media print {
  video{
 display:none;
}
}
```

the above code will hide the video in print page.